# Can we send "Notifications App" through Graph API?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have advanced further in my app, now I have two users who has allowed my app, Alice and Bob, now Alice wants to send notifications to invite Bob to an event in a place.

App Notifications:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/notifications/#impl

I don't know if I can use the graph api to do this, or I have to do it through HTTP like in the example. (I'd rather use Javascript, maybe FB.api? but how?)

By the way, how I get the access_token for use it? Is it always the same or this expires having to ask for it again?

PS.
Moreover, maybe this is out of topic -I don't know-, Is it possible to do this with Open Graph and what advantages would give us this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any tip would be great :)

Comment: I don't know who vote me negative and why... this question is out docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the `notifications`, yes you can use the API (PHP/JS), something like :

```
"/{recipient_userid}/notifications?PARAMS"
```

Learn about the `access tokens` [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/). You can get the token after user authorize your app. (detials in the link)

Open Graph is a different concept. Please read the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/). It totally depends on your requirement what exactly you are trying to implement.

Comment: Actually, both users authorized my app, and I just want to send a custom notification from A to B.
Could you be more specific in the Javascript call with a example?

Comment: I've written specific only, what else you want? `FB.api("/{REC_ID/notifications?PARAMS}");`

Comment: ah okok I didn't know how to send the request but you do it with FB.api, sorry but I'm a newbie in FB API I've just worked a little with it. But I tried now with my own params and is Ok, it works. Thanks ! (Please vote up my question, because I don't know who gave me a negative vote :(